# JavaScript asynchronous function Google Sheet API, data availability is delayed due to being a formula retrieval? How to overcome?

Tags: javascript, async-await, undefined, google-sheets-api, asynchronous-javascript

I'm writing a formula using Google Sheets `gapi.update`, and then immediately calling a function makeApiCall, attempting to retrieve the data from that cell, with `gapi.get.`

The first iteration of this retrieval query almost inevitably returns **`undefined`**, as the formula has not processed in time for the request.

I have tried making a for loop to repeat the request, in comparison to `!==null`, this loop executes the 4 iterations prior to retrieving a single response. However, the desired value is usually returned to the console after the second query. I also attempted to rewrite this with time delays, which don't appear to actually sleep, they simply delay displaying the data. I also attempted to rewrite with async function + await + return and managed to await the return of **undefined** but not loop for the required data.

Is there a simple way to either delay the requests. Or `awit` between each?

```
async function makeApiCall(pos) {
  var params = {
    spreadsheetId: 'GoogleSpreadsheetID',
    range: 'Sheet1!B1',
  };

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params);
    request.then(function(response) {
      dataOu = (response.result.values);
      if (dataOu.value !== null) {
        displayRes(pos)
      }
    });

  }
```

My expected result is that my global variable `dataOu` retrieves `>null` from the formula and if not it should repeat the query. 
Is there a way to write this as a proper asynchronous function in which the request is repeated if the desired response is not received. or a way of instituting a timer between for loop iterations. This is not a simple asynchronous call as it is not just waiting for a response it is wanting to retrieve a particular response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be easily possible with `await`:

```
async function makeApiCall(pos) {
    const params = {
        spreadsheetId: 'GoogleSpreadsheetID',  
        range: 'Sheet1!B1',  
    };

    let response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params);
    while (response.result.values == null) { // or whatever you need to check
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5)); // delay the loop a bit
        response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(params); // try again
    }
    const dataOu = (response.result.values);
    if (dataOu.value !== null) {
        displayRes(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution, I clearly need some more practice on writing Promises. Only thing is this code contains a for loop from the original and your while loop, only the while loop is necessary.

Comment: @psquizzle Ah ok, I was somehow under the impression that you wanted to do 4 requests.